# Sprite animation frames in Adobe Photoshop CC

Tags: animation, rpg

I am creating 64x64 px sprites for my game and want to test the animation play before saving the sprite sheet in game.

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WTIKj0xVg64) to learn, which told me:

1) Click Window->Timeframe

2) Add selected Frame

3) Click duplicate frame, then Tween frames in between. These icons on the bottom left of timeline:

[image]

The issue is, he doesn't show how to do it if my sprite needs to animate in place... only if it moves across a canvas as such:

[image]

My game uses Texture Packer to pack individual 64x64px images and then renders the frames. Therefore, I need to make little adjustments to the single frame in place, and animate them:

[image]
[image]

I tried selecting my next frame layer for my sprite and duplicating it, but it only ends up duplicating the first frame.

How can I add my selected layer in my Layers to the timeline?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to manually add all the frames for your animation. You don't need tweening unless you want to rotate or move the sprite from point A to B and have it automagically interpolate (be)'tween the key frames.

For walking, jumping, shooting animations, etc. You have to do it manually. There's no magic for that.

Here is a little guide to help you with how to use the timeline:

https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/creating-frame-animations.html